# Advantages using Number.MIN_VALUE over first element value when finding max value

Tags: javascript

I've seen a few algorithms using `Number.MIN_VALUE` as the start value of max when finding the highest value in an array. I cannot see the benefits of this. Here are two ways of providing the number 90.

```
var arr = [1, 10, 66, 90],
    len = arr.length,
    max = arr[0],
    i;

// find max number
for (i = 1; i < len; i += 1) {
    if (max < arr[i])
        max = arr[i];
}

console.log(max); // 90
```

Versus:

```
var arr = [1, 10, 66, 90],
    len = arr.length,
    max = Number.MIN_VALUE,
    i;

// find max number
for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    if (max < arr[i])
        max = arr[i];
}

console.log(max); // 90
```

I cannot see *any* advantage in using the second method using `Number.MIN_VALUE`. The *only* thing I can think about is *readability* perhaps.

Comment: First one will be _bit_ performant.

Comment: There's new way: `Math.max(...arr)`

Comment: Second one reliably returns `MIN_VALUE` when operating on an empty array, first one will return `undefined` in that case.

Comment: Hmmm, wouldn't be `Math.max.apply(null, arr);` be easier? Or as tushar said using es6

Comment: It doesn't matter that there's a method to do this for you - presumably it uses something similar internally in respect to whether it uses the first array value or MIN_VALUE as its starting point - and this is a question about *why* some choices are made and not whether there's a better way.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It would make more sense to return undefined on an array which contains no value, returning MIN_VALUE would indicate that the array has values.

Comment: @Karl, depends on your specs I suppose :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Indeed! :)